# cannot use command line arguments for vs code in mac (zsh)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use command line arguments for vscode, but it treats those arguments as if it were a directory

steps that are already done:
1- ran Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH from vs code
2- machine restarted for PATH to take effect

code command line syntax: code [path] [arguments], in the following case -h refers to help

refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

e.g.

```
code -h
```

gives:

```
The file /Users/dshamim/-h does not exist.
```

running "where code" gives:

```
code () {
    if [[ $# = 0 ]]
    then
        open -a "Visual Studio Code"
    else
        local argPath="$1"
        [[ $1 = /* ]] && argPath="$1"  || argPath="$PWD/${1#./}"
        open -a "Visual Studio Code" "$argPath"
    fi
}
/usr/local/bin/code
/usr/local/bin/code
```

any one experienced this or how to get the command line arguments to work ? I need to export the list of extensions by code --list-extensions

Comment: Your argument takes a file name but you passed it `-h`.

Comment: it should work with any of these command line arguments, including -h, ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a function `code` defined somewhere in your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`, depending on what shell you are using). It overrides the script `/usr/local/bin/code`.

The function itself is incorrect. `open -a "app name"` does not allow to pass arguments to the application and `open -a "Visual Studio Code" "$argPath"` passes the argument as if it was some location.

You need to find that function and remove it. Then you need to close the window with the CLI and open a new one.

Also, if you just want to pass `--list-extensions`, you can try doing this

```
ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/cli.js --list-extensions
```

Comment: thanks!, I'm not a pro mac user, but your post helped a lot - the code function was defined in my .zshrc file, found it and removed it

Comment: My code in `wsl` is `/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code`, it does not accept cmd parameters like `--version` but wants to install `.vscode-server` in my `home`. Strange.